# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I have a VPS hosting with Ubuntu installed

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Kernel version is `3.13.0-*`

I tried to install docker and I went through all steps [as mentioned here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/) and everything installed and worked fine with the exception of this:

> For Ubuntu Trusty, Wily, and Xenial, it’s recommended to install the
>   linux-image-extra kernel package. The linux-image-extra package allows
>   you use the aufs storage driver.
>
> To install the linux-image-extra package for your kernel version
>
> sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)

When I was trying to run this command I've been told that

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-042stab113.17
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-extra-3.13.0-042stab113.17'
```

Anyway seems like docker is installed and I can start it using

```
service docker start
```

And when I run this command it says that

```
docker start/running, process 12235
```

But when I check the status it says me that

```
docker stop/waiting
```

And when I try to start hello-world container it says me that

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
Error: failed to start containers: hello-world
```

I've already installed docker on my OS X following all steps from official tutorial and it worked fine,
but can't figure out what's wrong with my ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure about the problem here, but I always use the all-in-one script from https://docs.docker.com/linux/step_one/ with good results. You should uninstall everything you installed with the steps above first.

Comment: Any news on this issue?